# can not make sens of this type `void(C::* volatile)(int) const ` used in an example in C++ reference manual

Tags: c++, c++17, standards, pointer-to-member, qualifiers

In the C++17 standard draft document, in subsection (6.7.3) "CV-qualifiers" **[basic.type.qualifier]**: 
paragraph 6, there is this sentence:

> For a class type C, the type corresponding to the type-id `void(C::* volatile)(int) const`
>   has the top-level cv-qualifier volatile.

I have C language background and was randomly reading C++ standard and can't make sens of this, I tried to interpret it as

> a volatile function pointer to a function that can be called on const objects and that takes a single int argument and return a   ??? ( C type / void  I am lost here)

does someone have an explanation ?

I have tried this code

```
int main()
{
    class C 
    {
       public:
       typedef void(C:: * volatile X)(int)const ;
       void f(int z) const 
            {cout << z << endl;} 

       X a = (X)&f;  // had to add -fpermissive flag
    };

    C t;
    t.f(5); // works obviously
    (t.a)(5); // gives the following compilation message
```

```
main.cpp:22:18: warning: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&main()::C::f’ [-fpermissive]
        X a = (X)&f;
                  ^
main.cpp:27:12: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘t.main()::C::a (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* t.main()::C::a) (...)’
     (t.a)(5);
            ^
```

changing to what is adviced doesn't work !

thank you for your help

Comment: First part, constant member functions are explained in any C++ tutorial. `volatile` is a bit more complicated, but any object, just like it can be `const`, can also be `volatile`. Even if that object is a pointer to a member function.

Comment: I understand what are const and volatile, my question is about the type-id used in the example to illustrate top-level qualifier, and I can't make sens of this type-id the `C:: `  part especially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C::*` syntax denotes a member-function pointer which means a pointer to a member-function (sometimes called *a method*) that belongs to a class `C`.

In order to obtain an address of a member-function you need to use special syntax with qualified member-function name:

```
X a = &C::f;
```

In order to call a member-function via pointer you need to use a special operator `.*` (as your compiler advises):

```
(t.*(t.a))(5);
```

Note that we need to use `t` twice: for accessing `a` member and for calling `a` with `t` as `this`.

Comment: thanks very much, the `C::*`  was bothering me ,  now this clears things up.

Comment: but still this `(t.*a)(5)` does not work

Comment: played with it a little bit and looks like this `(t.*t.a)(5);`  works !! @

Comment: @walidTALABOULMA, great job figuring this out, I've missed it! I've updated the answer.